# How to restrict ‘ this special character in textarea using regular expression in java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a textarea name remarks. When i enter ‘ this special character in textarea at  the backend servlet I'm getting that value like ?(question mark) special character 
remarks============????????????????????????????????????????
and getting the below expetion

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x91\xC2\x91\xC2\x91...' for column 'remarks' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460)
```

I tried the below regular expression but the exception is not solved.

```
     if(remarks.matches("^[?]")){
                errors.put("remarks", "Invalid remarks!");
            }
```

Comment: why dont you restrict users to enter special character in jsp page itself. As per your current case, you allow user to do something and in backend you are restricting that then what is the use of allowing special charcter

Comment: try "\?", and you should restrict the input on client side by using javascript.

Comment: sometimes client side validations may fail. Thats why I'm using server side validations@SpringLearner

Comment: @Asha *sometimes client side validations may fail.* I dont think so